# Отправка сообщения с клиента на клиент без сервера

Tags: android

Задача такая. Нужно создать приложение,которое бы могло отправлять сообщения из одного приложения на другое без сервера.
Какие вообще есть способы реализации такого?

Answer (score 4):

Конечно есть. Т.н. [пиринговая сеть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

В общем, клиент одновременно является также и сервером.

Пример в [одной WiFi сети](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html).

Comment: а есть пример создания клиент сервера не для вай фай, а для интернет соединений.

Comment: Для прямого соединения двух устройств через интернет нужно как минимум что бы одно из устройств узнало адрес другого и по скольку широковещательные рассылки в глобальной сети невозможны, то таки нужен сервер или какойнить сервис через который можно будет обменяться адресами. Кроме того необходимо что бы хотя бы у одного из устройств был прямой внешний адрес, то есть такой адрес по которому через интернет будет доступно действительно это устройство, а не маршрутизатор провайдера.

Answer (score 1):

Для обмена сообщениями через веб можно использовать [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/), который позволяет клиентам контатировать друг с другом через браузер. Не все браузеры поддерживают эту [технологию](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/), можно использовать например Chrome или FireFox.

Но нужно первоначально установить соединение между клиентами с помощью сервера. Для этого можно использовать например [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) или [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

После установления соединения, сервер уже не нужен.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй такой метод:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time
import random
import socket
import string
import commands

HOST = "irc.oftc.net"
PORT = 6667
NICK = "py" + str( random.randint(1,1000) ) + "client"
IDENT = NICK
REALNAME = NICK
CHANNEL = "cNcXXX04vCPTpvseq"
readbuffer=""
s=socket.socket( )
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
s.send("USER %s %s %s :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, NICK, REALNAME))
s.send("JOIN #" + CHANNEL + " \r\n")
s.send("PRIVMSG #" + CHANNEL + " :i'm on-line!\r\n")
DELAY = 2.1
while 1:
        readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
        temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
        readbuffer = temp.pop( )
        for line in temp:
                line = string.rstrip(line)
                print line
                line = string.split(line)
                if line[0] == "PING":
                        s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
        #time.sleep(DELAY)
```

Запускаешь два python скрипта и вместо PING/PONG-а им чего-нибудь нарисуй.

Проблемой может быть, то что используется третья сторона - сервер irc.oftc.net. Ляжет сервер - ляжет связь между ботами.

Comment: "Задача такая. Нужно создать приложение,которое бы могло отправлять сообщения из одного приложения на другое без сервера." 
Зачем писать диаметрально противоположное тому что автор спрашивает.